# How to add entity in a table that have many to many relation ship using entity framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am facing a logic problem in asp.net web API. I have registration method for adding users where each user belongs to an account the relation between user and account is many to many "one account can add many users" and "user can exist in many accounts" so i have 3 tables. As a result when i till entity framework to add user it just add the information in table user i need also to make add account id in the 3rd table(result of many to many).

UserDetail is a view in the database contain both account id and user i check if user  exists or not if not i add user but unfortunately without account id.

```
UserDetail newUser = db.UserDetails.Where(newuser => newuser.UserMail == user.UserMail && newuser.AccId == accID).SingleOrDefault();
if (newUser == null)
{
    /*string passPhrase = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["PassPhrase"];
    string random_token = Crypto.RandomToken().ToString();
    string EnToken = Crypto.Encrypt(random_token, passPhrase);
    user.ConfirmToken = random_token;*/

    db.Users.Add(user);
    try
    {
        db.SaveChanges();
        //Mail.SendMail(EnToken,user.UserMail);
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted);
    }
    catch
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the account to the user or the user to the account.

Here's an example of adding an account to the user:

```
var newUser = db.UserDetails.FirstOrDefault(newuser => newuser.UserMail == user.UserMail && newuser.AccId == accID);
if (newUser == null)
{    
    var user = new User();
    var account = db.Accounts.FirstOrDefault(acc => acc === "some account");
    if(account != null)
    {
        //Depending on your entity, you may need to check if Accounts is null here.
        user.Accounts.add(account);
    }
    db.Users.Add(user);

    try
    {
        db.SaveChanges();
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted);
    }
    catch
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
}
```

If your classes look kind of like the following, then EF will automatically map the tables for you.

```
public class User
{
    public ICollection<Account> Accounts {get;set;}
}

public class Account
{
    public ICollection<User> Users {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: First thanks for your help. BY default entity framework dose not generates that mapping or i am wrong  user.Accounts.add(account); i have to map it on the model by myself

Comment: i am using entity framework database first the mapping dose not appear in the model if i updated the mode dose it work !

Comment: I'm sorry... Are you saying you update the model and now it works for you?

Comment: i say if i update the model dose the database will be updated. i am using entity framework database first

Comment: Yes, when using Entity Framework, if you update the model, the database relationships are updated.   That being said, because you're doing database first, I would create a simple test to ensure that the database tables are updated as you expect.  If you're doing DB first because the DB already exists, that's your only choice.  However, if you're doing DB first because you're trying to design the DB and then the code, I would suggest you try doing entity framework code first.  IMO, that would help you a lot.